# FullCalendar: allow event only to be moved from one resource to another

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar-scheduler

I tried many things (editable, eventContraint, ... ) how can I setup a FullCalendar, so that an event can only be changed from one resource to another, but that it is not allowed to change the start, end or duration?

I really have no clue in what direction to look for, I tried to work with businesshours, eventContraint,...

anybody has any clue or idea how this can be achieved?

Thanks...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the fullcalendar site https://fullcalendar.io/docs/resource_events/eventResourceEditable/

Preventing date changes, but allowing resource changes

If you'd like to allow the user to drag-n-drop an event to a different resource, you can set the master editable flag to false, but override it specifically for event resources:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
   defaultView: 'timeline',
   editable: false, // don't allow event dragging
   eventResourceEditable: true // except for between resources

   // resource and event data...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the accepted answer is outdated.

According to the docs (2023) to allow events only to be moved from one resource to another but not be able to change the start and end date you should use `eventStartEditable` and `eventDurationEditable`:

https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventDurationEditable

```
...
    editable: true, // don't allow event dragging
    eventStartEditable: false, // Allow events’ start times to be editable through dragging
    eventDurationEditable: false, // Allow events’ durations to be editable through resizing
...
```

that worked for me!